# What does $T(v_i)$ mean in the definition of Linear Transformation for some $T$ and basis vector $v_i$

Tags: linear-transformations, definition

I am unsure what does $T(v_i)$ means as shown in pictures below (I will type out the gist of it too)

Given a linear operator(transformation) $T$ on vector space $V$. Let a basis $B$ of $V$ be $B=\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n\}$ where $n = \operatorname{dim} V$.

The matrix representation of $T_B$ (relative to basis $B$) $$T_B= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$

So here is the part I do not understand: $$T(v_i) = a_{1i}v_1 + a_{2i}v_2 +...+a_{ni}v_n$$ This will give us the $i$th column of $T$

Is $T(v_i)$ a matrix multiplication of $T$ on $v_i$? Or does it simply refer to the $i$th column of T. The 2nd image I pasted shows my attempts at plugging in real values.

Also, just realised another obvious fact. If $T_B$$(v_i)$ = $a_{1i}v_i +a_{2i}v_2 + ... + a_{ni}v_n$, then $(a_{1i},a_{2i},...,a_{ni})$ should be the $i$th row instead of the $i$th column of $T_B$ since vectors are represented as columns and so the coefficients depend on the rows of the matrix to its left.

[This is from my study guide about linear transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c51oQ.png)

[I use excel to try working out T on 2 different bases](https://i.stack.igur.com/PvXYW.png)

Comment: Since $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator on $V$, the vector obtained by applying $T$ to a basis element $v_i$, $Tv_i$, can be uniquely represented as a linear combination of all the basis elements of $V$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I forgot to add(just edited and added it in) that apparently T = {T(v1) T(v2) ... T(vn)}, so we can see that T(vi) is supposed to return the ith column of T.

The problem i ran into is that T(vi)(matrix multiplication) only equals to the ith column when I am using standard basis.

Comment: I edited the question significantly to make it readable, fixed grammar, and added $\LaTeX$. I would recommend learning MathJax for future usage.

Comment: Thank you Don! Still trying to figure out how to get it to work(I am also starting on learning programming)